# Get duration as seconds google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm calculating some sums of gain over time - therefore I want to divide X by time required to generate X.

[image: image description]

The problem here is, that the `SECOND` function in the `=(SUM(B4:B18)/SECOND(SUM(A4:A18)))*60` formula returns **second portion** (mod 60), not second sum (with hours*3600 and minutes*60).

So how can I convert duration field into integer representing number of seconds for that duration?

Answer (score 1):

If your `0:01:00` is a date/time index (numeric rather than a string) the underlying number is an integer for days and a decimal for time. as there are 24*60*60 seconds in a day the number of seconds represented by `0:01:00` is effectively the number of seconds between midnight and one minute past midnight, which for A1 can be calculated as:

```
=86400*A1
```